# ClearML Web UI custom column not persistent

Tags: devops, clearml, trains

I'm using the experiments page of a project in ClearML Web UI to visualize some custom metrics. Therefore I've customized my table vie (https://allegro.ai/clearml/docs/docs/webapp/webapp_exp_table.html?highlight=customize#adding-metrics)
But whenever I leave the page for another project and go back, the table will be resetted.
Is there a way to store configuration for a specific project?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer I'm part of the ClearML (formerly Trains) team.

The layout for the table is stored by the Web UI on your user-preferences on the clearml-server, but it is not unfortunately a per project setting. This means that if you change the lable-layout in one project it, it will become the default table layout. I suggest you put feature request on the GitHub repo, it sounds reasonable to add.

Comment: Ok. I've opened an issue: https://github.com/allegroai/clearml/issues/314